# How to create a repeating background with xaml elements in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, graphics

I want to create an area in my application that looks draggable.  Usually, you see this done with a background of small dots or squares, or sometimes lines.  I'm using Silverlight and I want to simply create a background that is a set of repeating small rectangles.  I honestly cannot figure out how to generate a background with xaml.  I'd rather not have to create every little rectangle -- this will also cause the control not to scale.  Is there some way to repeat xaml elements to form a pattern?  This would be similar to CSS repeating backgrounds, but I would like to use xaml instead of images.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a brush, like this:

```
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="6,6" StartPoint="2,2" SpreadMethod="Repeat" MappingMode="Absolute">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFAFAFAF" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.339"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

I've nicked this particular example from the excellent [blacklight](http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/) project, you'll need to play around with all the different settings to see what does what. I'm guessing a radial brush will allow you to get dots, etc. I think they created it in blend as all the numbers were crazy decimals until I sanitised them a bit.

Comment: Thanks!  I found the same snippet.  I am wondering how to do it in 2 dimensions to get a rectangular pattern (like you said, radialBrush might help).  But this gets me on the right track.  

It still would be interesting to have a xaml repeater of sorts.  I guess I could just write my own layout control to do that.

Comment: I think a repeater wouldn't be very good performance wise (e.g. a thousand elements in a listbox takes a second or two to render).